# Google Translation API

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

Has anyone used Google translation API ? What is the max length limit for using it?

Answer (score 6):

At the moment there's no limit per project per day but certain limits apply on a combination of per minute, per project and per user basis. It also depends of what feature of the API you're using. Here you can read more about quota and limits

https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content

Answer (score 2):

500 characters

[source](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/google-launched-another-ajax-api-this.html#c8304624882908049429)

Comment: it could be.  i just googled for you.  i have never used the service.

Comment: Wrong.  See the comment in the link you cited right under the one that quoted 500 chars.

Comment: I don't argue that I might be wrong.  However, that comment is talking about a wrapper which removes character limitations.  Apples and oranges imho.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the throttle limit is 100,000 *characters* per *day*. Looks like you can apply to have that limit increased/removed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used it to translate Japanese to English.

I don't believe the 500 char limit is true if you use http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/, but one thing that is true is you're restricted as to the number of requests you can make within a certain period of time.  They also try to detect whether or not you're sending a lot of requests with a similar period, almost like a mini "denial of service" attack.

So when I did this I wrote a client with a random length sleep between requests.  I also ran it on a grid so all the requests didn't come from a single IP address.

I had to translate ~2000 Java messages from a resource bundle from Japanese to English.  It worked out pretty nicely, as long as the text was single words.  Longer phrases with context came out awkwardly.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at this link it will give the correct answer at the bottom of the page.

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq

> **What is the maximum number of characters per request?**
>   The maximum size of each text to be translated is 5000 characters, not including any HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can send source strings of up to 5,000 characters, but there are a
few provisos that are sometimes lost.

1. You can only send the 5,000 characters via the POST method.
2. If you use GET method, you are limited to 2,000-character length limit on urls. If a url is longer than that, Google's servers will just reject it.

   **Note**: 2,000-character limit including the path and the rest
   of the query string as well + you must count uri encoding (for instance every space becomes a %20, every quotation
   mark a %22)

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Translation API is optimized for translating of smaller requests. The recommended maximum length for each request is 5K characters (code points). However, the more characters that you include, the higher the response latency. For Cloud Translation - Advanced, the maximum number of code points for a single request is 30K. Cloud Translation - Basic has a maximum request size of 100K bytes.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas